# DB2 Date column with default of last day of previous month?

Tags: db2

I am trying to create a db2 table with a date column where the default is the last day of the previous month. In the create table statement, I am defining the column as:

```
"CLOSE_DATE" DATE NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT DATE(CURRENT_DATE - DAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAYS),
```

but I am getting an error:

> SQL0104N  An unexpected token "-
>   DAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAYS" was found
>   following "LT DATE(CURRENT_DATE". 
>   Expected tokens may include: 
>   "". SQLSTATE=42601

Is this just not allowed, or do I have some syntax error?

**Update** - I used:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME AFTER INSERT ON SCH.TABLE FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE SCH.TABLE SET CLOSE_DATE = DATE(CURRENT_DATE - DAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAYS)
```

which worked great. If anyone knows of a more succinct syntax, feel free to comment.

Comment: I realize that this is an old(er) post, but I thought I would point out that (at least in LUW 9.7), there is a [`LAST_DAY`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053630.html) function that will give the last day of the month based on a date expression (e.g., `LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE)`)  Unfortunately, `DEFAULT`s still don't allow any functions other than the built-in cast functions (see reason code 7 on [`SQLCODE -574`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00574n.html)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the syntax of the statement is correct.  If I run the query:

```
select CURRENT_DATE - DAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAYS from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

It executes and returns properly (2/28/2011, for today's date March 29).

Although I can't find anything that explicitly says mathematical functions aren't allowed in default values, the db2 [CREATE TABLE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000927.htm) syntax diagram looks like this for defaults, and functions aren't listed:

```
default-values

|--+-constant-------------------------------------------+-------|
   +-datetime-special-register--------------------------+   
   +-user-special-register------------------------------+   
   +-CURRENT SCHEMA-------------------------------------+   
   +-NULL-----------------------------------------------+   
   '-cast-function--(--+-constant------------------+--)-'   
                       +-datetime-special-register-+        
                       +-user-special-register-----+        
                       '-CURRENT SCHEMA------------'
```

I also tried the following test:

```
create table test (
test_column integer with default 1
);

create table test2 (
test_column integer with default (2 - 1)
);
```

test was created, test2 was not.

I think you can accomplish what you want with a trigger that fires after insert.